# D3 mask creation

Tags: d3.js, mask

I'm working on a project [here](http://bl.ocks.org/tomstove/5642750) and I'm trying to apply a mask to the roads so that the coloured rectangles are only opaque where the roads would be. I'm a little stuck on finding information about using masks with D3. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks, Tom

Comment: Hi Tom, maybe I misunderstand the question, but if you already know how to determine which rectangles need the "mask", you could just use the d3 `classed` method to apply a CSS class to them, and then control the opacity of road vs non-road rectangles via CSS

Comment: I worked out a solution, the code can be found [here](http://gist.github.com/5655197). Thanks @Jonah for your response, I appreciate it